# Insert formula to cell A3 based on a value of A1 in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, validation, if-statement, return, formula

Dears,

let us say, I have number 1 in A1 in MS Excel.
I am running an IF statement in A2, BUT in case of "TRUE" validation, **I want the A3 cell get inserted with a formula or value,**
**instead of having the A2 being filled and getting the result.**
IF(A1=1;...**enter formula of {=SUM(A10:A20)}  but to cell A3**)

I can not use VBA for security purposes, any ideas? If another formula is more suitable, please say so.

Thank you All in advance.

Getting a formula as a result in case of TRUE validation, to a different cell, where the IF statement is inserted/running from.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the formula `=IF(A2, SUM(A10:A20), "")` in A3 will fulfil your requirement. If instead you want the literal text `=SUM(A10:A20)` in A3, then use `=IF(A2, "=SUM(A10:A20)", "")`.

Comment: Hello Wibble, thanks for your answer.
I have a value to be validated in A1, that is number 1 or something.
I want to have the IF statement, validation in A2.
And I want my result, a formula that will run, not a literal text, not to returned/written to A2, but to A3.
Thanks.

Comment: So the first option should work. If A2 is TRUE, it will show the sum of A10 to A20. If A2 is FALSE, it will be blank.

Comment: Yes, but I want the SUM(A10:A20) to be written to A3, not to A2 and want to have the IF formula in A2.

Comment: If you want something to appear in A3, you need the formula to be in A3.